# Minimum number of Hamiltonian paths in a strongly connected tournament on $n$ nodes

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

For $n\ge3$ let $a(n)$ be the minimum possible number of [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in a [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) on $n$ nodes.

> What is a good (or at least nontrivial) lower bound for $a(n)$? What is a good reference for this question? Is $a(n)$ in the [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/)?

**My attempt:** All I know is that $a(3)=3,a(4)=5,$ and $a(5)=9$ which I found by counting by hand. (In a strongly connected tournament on $5$ nodes, the number of Hamiltonian paths can be $9,\ 11,\ 13,$ or $15.$) Trivially $a(n)\ge n$ (because a strongly connected tournament has a Hamiltonian cycle), and $a(n)$ is odd by  [Rédei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_R%C3%A9dei)'s theorem.

**Update.** As suggested in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688155/minimum-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-strongly-connected-tournament-on-n-no#comment3445472_1688155) by @Michael, for each $n\ge3$ there is a strongly connected tournament on $n$ nodes with exactly $2^{n-2}+1$ Hamiltonian paths; namely, take a transitive tournament and reverse the arc between the first and last nodes. This proves that $a(n)\le2^{n-2}+1.$ Is $a(n)=2^{n-2}+1$?

> For $n\ge3,$ does every strongly connected tournament of $n$ nodes have at least $2^{n-2}+1$ Hamiltonian paths? (True for $n=3,4,5.$) **[Nope — see the third update.]**

**Update.** It's easy to see that $a(n+1)\ge a(n)+n-1,$ whence it follows by induction that $a(n)\ge\lfloor(n-1)^2/2\rfloor+1=$ [OEIS sequence A099392](http://oeis.org/A099392),
so I guess the **trivial bounds** are
$$\lfloor(n-1)^2/2\rfloor+1\le a(n)\le2^{n-2}+1.$$

**Update.** Consider the transitive tournament with nodes $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6$ and arcs $v_iv_j\ (1\le i\lt j\le6).$ Let $T$ be the strongly connected tournament obtained from this transitive tournament by reversing the arcs $v_1v_5$ and $v_4v_6.$ Then $T$ has exactly $15$ Hamiltonian paths, showing that $a(6)\le15.$ An obvious generalization of this construction shows that $$a(n)\le2^{n-2}-2^{n-4}+3.$$

Comment: If you take the "strongly connected" part out, the answer is "1," achieved by an ordering $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ on the nodes such that a link is always directed to the higher-ordered node. Perhaps similar structures are "min cases" for strongly connected situations.

Comment: @Michael By "similar structure" do you mean, take that transitive tournament and reverse the arc from $1$ to $n$? That gives a tournament with $2^{n-2}+1$ Hamiltonian paths, proving that $a(n)\le2^{n-2}+1.$ Can you prove that every strong tournament has at least that many Hamiltonian paths?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "similar structure," or perhaps something like it.  The bound $2^{n-2}+1$ seems to match your known values for $a(3), a(4), a(5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [the same question at Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234029/the-minimum-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-strongly-connected-tournament-of-or) and [Fedor Petrov answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234029/the-minimum-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-strongly-connected-tournament-of-or/234093#234093) there by referring to the paper ["A Note on the Number of Hamiltonian Paths in Strong Tournaments"](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1n3) by Arthur H. Busch where it is shown that $a(n)$ is approximately $5^{\frac{n-1}3}.$